# generating a queryset by filtering for multiple values

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to create a view that returns a queryset based on multiple values.

The pseudo code logic of what I'm trying to do is below.

```
Model.objects.filter(author = dave or author = steve)
```

can this be done in a single query? If not then what is the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#in) lookup:

```
Model.objects.filter(author__in=['dave', 'steve'])
```

Comment: Excellent. Ruddra suggested that I use Q but since I already have lists of values this seems more appropriate. Thanks.

Comment: what if author__in =[queryset1, queryset2]. how to do in this case filtering a single field with multiple queryset values rather than string.plz help..

Answer (score 1):

Use [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

Example:

```
Model.objects.filter(Q(author='Dave') | Q(author='Steve'))
```

Comment: Thanks. I tested this and it worked but I chose the answer by catavaran because my values were already in lists.